# How to deal with transitive dependencies when osgiying a third party library with Maven Bundlor

Tags: maven-2, bundlor

I want to use hibernate 4 in my osgi project, therefore I need to make hibernate 4 and its dependencies osgi plugins so that they are available in osgi runtime. I am using maven bundlor to do this. Because hibernate depends on several other libraries, some of which have transitive dependencies as well. Is there a way to let maven automatically finds all hibernate 4's dependencies and make all available in osgi runtime?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the pax library](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/help/wrap-jar.html) to wrap the jars from the command line. Or if you store your artifacts in a Nexus repository, take a look at [this bundle-maker plugin](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+Bundle+Maker): it generates the bundles on the fly if they don't exist already when a dependency has a `<classifier>osgi</classifier>`. I use the second approach and although buggy when configuring, it does the job

As a third option, create poms that will use maven-bundle-plugin to wrap the jars. I use this approach when i need to customize the BND directives to exclude imports or change exports
The parent wrapper pom I generated from the [pax-maven-plugin](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/wrap-jar-mojo.html) and each wrapped jar inherits from this pom

They all use BND internally btw

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the bundles available on Maven Central? [This link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate%22) provides a list of all hibernate bundles. You'll notice that hibernate-core version 4.0.1.Final is available with the following maven dependency XML:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>   <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Hi Jon7,thanks for the reply, but the hibernate jars in maven central repo are plain old jars, not osgi bundles. And there are no hibernate 4x bundles available in the spring repo as well(only 3.x).Although i can live with hibernate 3 at the moment, but creating a custom osgi bundle for a third party library will eventually become a problem at some point.

Comment: You can just use bnd's wrap command to wrap the jar and you still get the benefit of Maven dependency resolution. Unless hibernate has any code that's not osgi-friendly, I would think a simple wrap would be sufficient?